# Spring Boot Webclient - Merge

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to merge 2 responses and return a Flux.

```
private Flux<Response<List<Company>, Error>> loopGet(List<Entity> registries, Boolean status) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(registries)
            .flatMap(this::sendGetRequest)
            .mergeWith(Mono.just(fetch(status)));

}
```

This is what I am doing, is working but I would like the merge to wait before calling the Mono.just (fetch (status)).
I'll explain, sendGetRequest returns a Mono that makes an API call and from the result saves things to db. Subsequently the merge goes to call the db with the fetch method, but that data is not updated yet. If I then make the call again, I get the updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `concatWith` and `fromCallable` to ensure that fetch is called lazily after the get requests are finished.

```
private Flux<Response<List<Company>, Error>> loopGet(List<Entity> registries, Boolean status) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(registries)
            .flatMap(this::sendGetRequest)
            .concatWith(Mono.fromCallable(() -> fetch(status)));

}
```